# In Java I get this error: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, package

Why I get the  error: cannot find symbol in this code when I ejecute it in console, but in IntelliJ it runs ok.

File: MockSongs.java

```
package day14;

import java.util.*;

public class MockSongs {
  public static List<String> getSongsStrings() {
    List<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();
    songs.add("somersault");
    songs.add("cassidy");
    songs.add("$10");
    songs.add("havana");
    songs.add("Cassidy");
    songs.add("50 ways");
    return songs;
  }
}
```

File: Jukebox1.java

```
package day14;

import java.util.*;

public class Jukebox1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }

  public void go() {
    List<String> songsList = MockSongs.getSongsStrings();
    System.out.println(songsList);
  }

}
```

This is the error:

```
java Jukebox1.java
Jukebox1.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    List<String> songsList = MockSongs.getSongsStrings();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable MockSongs
  location: class Jukebox1
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

This is my Java version:

```
openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7, mixed mode)
```

I Tried to delete de statement `package day14` at the beginning but it doesn't work.
Also Visual Studio Code recognize the MockSongs Class but in console I get the error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Looks like you didn't compile your Java source to bytecode.  java.exe accepts .class files, not .java source files.  Learn how to compile using javac.exe.

Comment: You should be running `java day14.Jukebox1` for that to work (if you compile correctly). You don't say where your classes are relative to that directory...

Comment: It doesn't compiles either. I can say day14 is the root directory. The weird thing is IntelliJ can run the Jukebox1 java file but in console it doesn't work.

Comment: `javac -d . *.java;java day14.Jukebox1`

Comment: Wow! It works! I don't understand why.

Comment: Well in that case, you need to a little more study on packages and the classpath